# HTML não executa quando dentro de uma variavel PHP

Tags: php, html

Bom dia amigos.

Estou retornando um código html através do BD em php, quando dou um echo na variável ao invés de executar o código html ele exibe como se fosse um texto alguém sabe me ajudar?

Desde já, obrigado

```
<div class="papel" id="papel" style="margin-top:calc(297mm * <?php echo $i?>)!important;background-color:<?php echo $cor ?>">
<?php    
    $listagem = new Consulta();
    $listagem->Conecta();
    $retorno = $listagem->ConsultaDados('cf_codigo', 'dm_id', 'ASC','dm_id=71');
    if(count($retorno) > 0) {
        foreach ($retorno as $linha) {
        // Ao executar essa linha, ao inves do codigo html na variavel ser executado, é é escrito.
            echo $linha->dm_codhtml;
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código que vc já tem

Comment: Olá Anderson! Podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar o código a que te referes?

Comment: @Sergio adicionei o código e uma imagem, acredito que facilite a compreensão.

Comment: @Anderson qual é o problema de colocar o código em texto? Assim podemos usar o código na resposta, sem ele (ou como imagem) é muito mais dificil e faz-nos perder mais tempo para te poder ajudar...

Comment: Aconteceu um problema parecido comigo, resolvi assim.(Adaptando ao seu exemplo)

echo "{$linha->dm_codhtml}";

Comment: Você poderia tentar esse código? `echo addslashes($linha->dm_codhtml);` ou `<<<HTML echo $linha->dm_codhtml HTML;` ?

Comment: PedroFranco e RafaelWithoeft obrigado, tentei os dois porém sem sucesso. Ambos aparecem o mesmo código idêntico a figura.

Comment: A apresentação de html pelo php, não fornecido pelo banco de dados `<?php echo <span>teste</span>; ?>` funciona normalmente? Ou ambos estão exibindo o código html na tela como um texto?

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft realizei o teste e aparentemente o problema é quando a variavel é exibida com dados do banco... `<?php echo "<span>teste</span>"; ?>`  Desta Maneira é executado corretamente,

Comment: @Anderson conseguiu resolver? Gostaria de olhar melhor seu código, tem outra forma de contato para que eu possa te ajudar? E-mail?

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado. ainda não consegui, estou tentando, meu email é andersonsanches@outlook.com

Answer (score 4):

O código HTML está vindo encodado do banco de dados. Você precisa desencodá-lo.

Ao invés de fazer assim:

```
echo $linha->dm_codhtml;
```

... faça assim:

```
echo html_entity_decode($linha->dm_codhtml);
```